# Running Camel-Context without using Thread.sleep() method

Tags: apache-camel

While starting the camel-context, Thread.sleep() method needs to call. Can somehow it can be made avoidable?
Can it be done using wait() and notify() mechanism.

I am trying to implement the camel-context for my project. I need to remove the call to make thread waiting for some amount of time, like Thread.sleep(5000) used here.
Can anybody has idea.

```
        CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
        CsvRouteBuilder builder = new CsvRouteBuilder(instId, csvcolMap);
        ctx.addRoutes(builder);
        ctx.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        ctx.stop();
```

Logic for implementing camel-context without using Thread.sleep(5000)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Camel `Main` class you can use that can keep the JVM running. See the example at (for Camel 3): https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-main

For Camel 2.x its similar but the `Main` class on 2.x has less functionality than on 3.x.

Comment: The example which is there in the link, the StandaloneCamel is using the CamelContext where again after starting the context it is going in sleep mode for around 10 secs before stopping it. I want to remove this sleep part from my code.

Comment: No look at the `MyApplication` as its using the main class. The standalone was to demonstrate how much more code you need to write without the main class.

Comment: I will check this again, thanx for the support. Also I have some other doubts on operations related to the file handling. So can I have discussion with u, if u don't mind. That will be very useful.

Comment: I suggest to ask on either the gitter chat room, or use the user mailing list for such open ended questions

Comment: can I get ur email id?

Comment: But 1 doubt, the main method is not stopping ie the call to method main.stop() is not called. So can we make use of that as well.

Comment: Yes you can stop the JVM, eg ctrl + c etc or anyway you stop a JVM, and the Main will shutdown gracefully. Or you can call the stop method on the main instance to stop also.

Comment: Thanx, I will check this. If I will use main.stop() or main.completed() method, so I don't need to add thread.sleep() in between them.